# Docker-in-docker/GitLab CI: adding and using credential helper

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry, gitlab-auto-devops

For my organization I am building a GitLab CI/CD pipeline for one of our projects. One job in this pipeline will be executed on a Docker executor GitLab runner running on one of our own servers. The job involves using image `docker:20.10.20` together with service `docker:20.10.20-dind`. The goal is to build a Docker image from my project that is uploaded in the project's container registry **hosted on gitlab.com itself (so NOT on Amazon ECR)**. I have this up and running with the following job configuration in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
docker-image-build:
  stage: Docker image build
  image: docker:20.10.20
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.20-dind
      alias: docker
  tags:
    - docker-runner
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
    - docker build --pull -m 3g --memory-swap -1 -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --build-arg FOO=$FOO --build-arg BAR=$BAR .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
```

However, at the `docker login` command in the `script` I get a cybersecurity related warning:

```
Login Succeeded
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
```

Storing credentials unencrypted in an artefact that might stick around is a big problem for us, as we are very concerned about cybersecurity. However, I can't seem to find a way to install [docker-credential-helpers](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) in the docker-in-docker container. (I'd like to or think I have to use the ````` pass```` based credential helper.) It seems to be a very barebone Linux image without a package manager or compiler. It only has tools such as wget and tar, so I could be able to download binaries and I can in fact install the ````` docker-credential-pass`binary itself. But I'm mostly stuck with no way to get`pass`installed, let alone its dependency`gpg``` along with a sufficient source of entropy.

I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Should I switch to a shell executor in this case?

Thank you in advance!
Joshua

Comment: Have you inspected a running container of the image that you pushed to the registry, do you see the `/root/.docker/config.json` in there? You build a new image within this job and from my understanding this file will not end up in the image. It gets created within the container that is created via the docker executor, which at the end of the pipeline gets removed.